# Atom PHP debug does not navigate to or highlights other files

Tags: php, debugging, atom-editor, xdebug

I'm testing Atom for PHP development and now I'm testing the debugger.

The problem is, when I click step in the expected behavior is to the next file to be opened and the current line to be highlighted, which does not happen it just stays in the same file, which is bad for when I want to click continue and stop on uncaught exceptions.

Everything else works fine, the callstack, the context, watches, and breakpoints, I can still track manually the lines via the Stack Trace, but it's not ideal for debugging, wasting time finding the files and scrolling for the line.

Even when I open the file there is no highlighting, the highlighting returns when the program gets back to to the file that activated the breakpoint

Is there any other package I missed installing?

Using Windows 7 with Atom 1.27.1 php-debug 0.3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it

I did not set the path map correctly, the default path map for the debugger is where the breakpoint file is in, but it called other files from outside of that path, setting the path map to the server root folder solved the problem